# How can I join a dataframe and invert the joining column?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have two dataframes which I wish to join:

```
df1 = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

   col1 
0     1     
1     2     
2     3     
3     4    
4     5     

df2 = {'col2': ['nan', 'nan', 3, 4]}

   col2 
0     nan     
1     nan     
2     3     
3     4
```

Currently I would like to join the two dataframes. However, I would like for the second dataframe (df2) to be added from the bottom as shown below:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     nan
1     2     nan
2     3     nan
3     4     3
4     5     4
```

How might I do this? I currently have tried using `pandas.join()` but have had no luck with this.

Essentially I want to append from the bottom, as shown by the output, there is another null value that is created in the first row of the output.

Comment: Use left join by index and column.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Im not sure why you had to close the question... @jezrael

Comment: hmmm, because it seems there is match by index of df2 and column `col1` in df1, I am wrong?

Comment: My bad, my goal was to join the two dataframes but I would like to have the second column added from the bottom rather than the top

Answer (score 1):

Idea is set index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) in `df2` by index of df1 from bottom by indexing for same length and then is used [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4]})

idx = df1.index[-len(df2):]

df = df1.join(df2.set_index(idx))
print (df)
   col1  col2
0     1   NaN
1     2   NaN
2     3   NaN
3     4   3.0
4     5   4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': ['nan', 'nan', 3, 4]})
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

output

```
    col1    col2
0   1   nan
1   2   nan
2   3   3
3   4   4
4   5   NaN
```